# ios - URL Schema

Tags: iphone, ios, schema

In my iPhone App i have an option to download pdf or doc files. 
When I am clicking download button I need to open USB Disk app.

How can I do this?!

Does anyone know if there is a URL schema for launching the built in USB Disk app?!

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Answer (score 0):

Upto now, there is no builtin app like 'USB Disk' in iOS.

Comment: This is not a built in app. it is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/usb-disk/id370531520?mt=8

Comment: Then why do you say it is 'built in' in your question?

Comment: @Dev you should visit 'USB Disk' developer's website, and study the 'USB Disk' features wether is support the feature that you want or not, i-e wether it can be launched from other apps or not.

Answer (score 0):

**If app already installed than open the USB Disk app**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
                               [NSURL URLWithString:@"USB Disk app url scheme://"]]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
                               [NSURL URLWithString:@"USB Disk app url scheme://"]];
}
```

Comment: You will have to work out what the URL Scheme is for the USB Disk App (assuming it has one) and replace that in the code above.  Perhaps contact the developer of the app.